# Python Increment two strings at the same time

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to be able to interate both `list1 = list('asdf')` and `list2 = list('qwer')` at the same time. What is the best approach?

```
for i, p in list1, list2:
    print(i,p)
```

Where `i` would be increment `list1` and `p` would be increment `list2`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) (or [`itertools.izip`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) if the two lists are large):

```
for i, p in zip(list1, list2):
    print(i, p)
```

Alternately, if `list1` might not be the same length as `list2` use [`izip_longest` from `itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest)

Comment: @IntriquedMan - glad I could help and welcome to Stackoverflow!  If this answer is what you needed you can accept it by clicking the green checkmark.  Enjoy the site!

Comment: awesome ! its great :)